# Null Pointer Exception with arrays and classes - Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, global-variables

Ok, so I have a global array as part of the Class "Temp". I want to edit that array from anywhere in the program. That is working fine. However, when I try to use those values to set values in my "Cords" Class, I get a Null Exception Error.
I have commented it in my code. Any idea why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k<4; k++){

            Temp.tempValues[k] = 0;

        }

        boolean checkNums = false;

        String coords = "";


        while(n<1 || n>2000){

            System.out.println("Enter number of lines");

            n = inp.nextInt();


        }

        Cords[] lines = new Cords[n];

        int proceed = 0;

        inp.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){

            proceed = 0;

            checkNums = false;

            while((proceed != 3) || (checkNums == false)){

                System.out.println("Enter line coordinates. "+(i+1));

                coords = inp.nextLine();

                proceed = checkSpaces(coords);

                checkNums = rightNums(coords);

            }

            lines[i] = new Cords();

            lines[i].setValues(Temp.tempValues[0], Temp.tempValues[1], Temp.tempValues[2], Temp.tempValues[3]);


        }

    }

    public static int checkSpaces(String sent){

        int spaces = 0;

        for(int y = 0; y< sent.length(); y++){

            if(sent.charAt(y)==' '){

                spaces++;

            }

        }

        return spaces;

    }

    public static boolean rightNums(String sent){


        int z = 0;

        int l = 0;

        String num = "";

        while(z<sent.length()){

                while((z<sent.length())&&(sent.charAt(z) != ' ')){

                    num += sent.charAt(z);

                    z++;

                }

                if(Integer.parseInt(num) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(num) >=10000){

                    return false;

                }else{

                    Temp.tempValues[l] = Integer.parseInt(num);

                    num = "";
                    z++;

                    l++;
                }

            }

        return true;

    }

    public class Cords{

        int x1 = 0;
        int x2 = 0;
        int y1 = 0;
        int y2 = 0;

        public void setValues(int xx1, int yy1, int xx2, int yy2){

            x1 = xx1;
            y1 = yy1;
            x2 = xx2;
            y2 = yy2;

        }

}

    public static class Temp{

        static int[] tempValues = new int[4];

    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: One cannot have, two public class in single file.

Comment: It is needed, as I will be posting code online, and can only be read from the one file

Comment: Try to remove "public" from that cord class, and then try your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `lines` array does not contain any object. It just contains `null`s and you can't invoke methods on `null`-values.

Since you are iterating over your `lines` array, initialize the current element before you invoke methods on it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = new Cords();

    lines[i].setValues(...);
}
```

You also have to make the `Cords` class static.

Comment: Sorry, i is in a for loop, my mistake. Forgot to type it out

Comment: at `lines[i] = new Cords()` I get error:
No enclosing instance of type solution is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with enclosing instance of type solution. (Eg. x.new A()where x is an instance of Solution

Comment: Please show all of your code. Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: A lot of it is probably distracting

Comment: If Cords class is static, can I still make objects?

Comment: Yes, but you could also move it out of the `Solution` class.

Comment: I'm not allowed to do that, but your solution worked and I'm very grateful

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Cords[] lines = new Cords[5];

    for(int k = 0; k<4; k++){
        Temp.tempValues[k] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        lines[i] = new Cords();
    lines[i].setValues(Temp.tempValues[0], Temp.tempValues[1], Temp.tempValues[2], Temp.tempValues[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: No enclosing instance of type solution is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with enclosing instance of type solution. (Eg. x.new A()where x is an instance of Solution

Comment: at `lines[i] = new Cords()`

Comment: @JohnDoe what do you want to say?